# List search results not appearing for other users

Tags: 2013, list, search

I added ~100 items to a list and ran an incremental crawl on the list (not sure if needed - we don't have Continuous enabled). Search results are returned correctly.

However if I login as a Test User (with Contribute permissions), the list search results don't return anything.

How do I troubleshoot this problem?

[image]

Giving the Test User Owner Permissions/Full Control (or even Site Collection Owner) didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

Sometime we also face this kind of issue. If crawl is completed and we add new users they will not able to search the items. So after adding users we perform crawl once again. This resolves issue for us.

Comment: To add what PS said, when a user get's some new permissions the objects always needs to be re-crawled before showing up in the search results. This stretch out from sites down to single items. So make sure that you have a good crawl scheme to reduce the time users have to wait to be able to use the search for finding new items.